# Ill-conditioned stiffness matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-element, numerics, c++, stiffness

I am writting a Fem code in c++ for a 2d plane stress model. My question is regarding the assembly stiffness matrix.I noticed that some elements of the matrix are not exactly zero but insted a number close to zero for example  -1.7677e-15. Can floating point arithmetic erros result to an ill-conditioned stiffness matrix? If yes how can I avoid it?

Comment: Did you initialize everything to 0?

Comment: Yes, I initialize the stiffness matrix to 0 and I did the assembly.However I took this kind of out when a operation like -6.77+6.77 takes place in some matrix positions

Comment: Yea, that looks to be machine precision subtraction error. Doesn't guarantee that the matrix is ill-conditioned. ill-conditioning is a ratio of the largest to smallest eigenvalue, not the largest and smallest values; otherwise every sparse matrix would have an infinite condition number.

Comment: Small round-off errors in constructing your stiffness matrix won't make your stiffness matrix ill-conditioned if it wasn't ill-conditioned in exact arithmetic.  If the theoretical exact arithmetic stiffness matrix is ill-conditioned then such round off errors can make things work.

Comment: The matrix may have small negative entries, but is that a problem? I see no real issue with this by itself.

Comment: I meant to type "can make things worse", but somehow "worse" became "work"

Comment: Thank all fot your comments.Can these errors hurt the convergenve of a solver like CG?I asking because I am using CG to solve an static FE model Ku=F and If replace these floating errors with 0s I have convergence else I don't